# Radio Button como configurar por favor me ajudem

Tags: javascript, eclipse, radiobutton

Estou fazendo um projeto de criação de aplicativo aqui na faculdade voltado para gerador de energia, para isso estamos utilizando o *Eclipse*, no caso gostaria de saber

```
if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
```

Como faz para quando a pessoa clicar nesse botão ele emitir uma resposta? aguardo resposta

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um escutador para o `radio`, mas não faz sentido verificar se ele está checado, pois o `radio` sempre estará checado ao ser clicado (ao contrário do `checkbox`, que pode ser checado e deschecado).

O escutador seria assim:

```
var radio = document.querySelector('#radioButton1');
radio.addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert("checado");
});
```

Onde a `id` do `radio` que deseja escutar seja `#radioButton1`.

Exemplo:

```js
var radio = document.querySelector('#radioButton1');

radio.addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert("checado");
});
```

```html
<input id="radioButton1" name="radio" type="radio" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" />
```